# How to stop VSCode having colored tab names

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since some recent update, VSCode started adding colors to tab names as seen here:

[image]

The blue, orange. No idea what the colors mean.

But I want to turn it off and have all tabs be black if it's possible.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I assume you are using the Insiders' Build.  You can disable those tab "decorations" with these settings:

`Workbench > Editor > Decorations: Colors`
`Workbench > Editor > Decorations: Badges`

Those would override your `tab foreground` if you don't disable them.

Then you color your `tab` colors if you need to.

Answer (score 6):

Go to settings.json and paste

```
 "tab.inactiveForeground": "#000000",
 "tab.activeForeground": "#000000",
```

The first one is for the color of the inactive tab name and the second one is for the color of the active tab name.

P.S. don't forget to put it inside

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
     "tab.inactiveForeground": "#yourcolor",
     "tab.activeForeground": "#yourcolor",
}
```

Comment: better to modify it based on theme name

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818022/2745495) is how to disable the colorings completely. But if you instead wanted to customize the colors, you can adjust various properties (documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)) in your `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting:

- `list.errorForeground`: Files containing errors.
- `list.warningForeground`: Files containing warnings.
- `gitDecoration.addedResourceForeground`: Added Git files.
- `gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground`: Modified Git files.
- Several other git related settings, see documentation linked above.

Note that these all will also affects the filename coloring in the sidebar/explorer view. I don't think there's a way to separate these, as they're both controlled by the same setting.

Example in settings.json:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]":  {                       // Optional - limit to a specific theme
    {
        "list.errorForeground":"#ff00ff", // make errors purple just for fun
    },
```