# Text color in tabs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the picture you see the tabs in the Monokai theme. Where is the color for the brown text defined (Database.coffee)? It doesn't seem to be defined in the Monokai theme but somewhere else.

I would want to make all the text as white, but setting `"tab.activeForeground": "#ffffff"` doesn't have any effect for those brown ones.

[image]

Comment: Do you want all tabs to have the same white text? Or you want to replace yellow with different color?

Comment: I would want to make all the text as white, but setting "tab.activeForeground": "#ffffff" doesn't have any effect for those brown ones.

Comment: Then does this answer your question? [How to stop VSCode having colored tab names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65807608/how-to-stop-vscode-having-colored-tab-names)

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks! Would still like to remove those file type badges as well, but this is a big improvement.

Comment: There might be a setting for that too, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [a color picked](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/b1ce0eda2dd4980b93e4b552c6573fa0afa9ee32/extensions/git/package.json#L2155) to identified modified git resource.

Overwrite it by:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#FF8A80"
  }
}
```

And to disable the git decorations overall as the comment suggested

```json
{
  "git.decorations.enabled":false
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there's a boolean flag that completely disables git decorations for tab names. I'd use that one.

Comment: I meant `"workbench.editor.decorations.badges": false, "workbench.editor.decorations.colors": false,`, if you want to disable git deco only for tab names, but leave them everywhere else.