How to turn off file name coloration in VS Code

Whenever I type something new in my vscode file, the filename become red with the number.
I think that's the reason why my vscode suggest is very slow.
For example,when I type f,about 1 second  later it will show to suggestion box.
Help me to fix this

You can disable the file name highlight with:
"workbench.editor.decorations.colors": false,

And the red 1 (number of errors) indicator with:
"workbench.editor.decorations.badges": false,

But this is purely aesthetical, and has nothing to do with the lag. I recommend replacing the stock C++ extension with Clangd, from my experience it works faster.

you closed https://stackoverflow.com/q/67768720/11107541 as a duplicate before, and had comments on the answer there.

@starball Oh! Forgot about it.

no problem. I've personally tried a year-ish ago to start as a habit to google setting IDs before writing answers to new questions- it helps find any existing questions that could be a dup target. not saying you have to do this, but I've found it helpful. I usually in the process find a bunch of stuff to close to a canonical dup target.
