# How to change the terminal's active tab border color in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to change the **terminal active tab border color** in VS Code as I tried to change it inside my **JSON** file by using this `"terminal.tab.activeBorder": "#fff"` piece of code inside my **workbench.colorCustomizations**, but I don't know why it's not working and the color is not getting changed. So can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Do you mean the editor tabs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843246/vscode-tab-color-not-responding-to-customization/67845465#67845465)?

Comment: @TimothyG. No not editor tabs, he means what he said, terminal tabs.

Comment: There is an actual unique selector for terminal tabs that I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day Sunny Raj,

If you want to change the **terminal active tab border color** then you make it through adding following line of code to the theme's JSON file with any color you prefer (here is the yellow as an example):

```
"panelTitle.activeBorder": "#ffc600"
```

But keep in mind, you can loose your customization in case of update of original theme. So I do recommend to fork theme's files you like on GitHub, modify it and then install it manually to your machine. You can also change terminal active title:

```
"panelTitle.activeForeground": "#ffc600"
```

I hope it will help you to achieve desirable results. Please, don't hesitate to ask me if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks @Raymoff. It did gave me the desired result. BTW after asking here for help after sometime I myself figured it out and forgot to remove the question from here. Anyways thanks a lot for your answer and suggestion.