# How to Customize Visual Studio Code Tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code (v1.59). As of now, the default theme of VSCode doesn't have distinguishable Tab coloring. For example, the Active Tab looks almost similar to the inactive tab.
So I need to know how can I change it.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843246/vscode-tab-color-not-responding-to-customization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your user settings.json (Ctrl+,)
or Search *"workbench.color..."* in the setting's search box.

Add Following lines under `"workbench.colorCustomizations"`

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Material Theme Ocean High Contrast]": {
    "tab.activeBorder": "#ff0000", //<--- applies to this specific theme: Material Theme Ocean High Contrast
},
    "tab.activeBorder": "#ff0000", //<--- applies to all theme
    "tab.unfocusedActiveBorder": "#000000"
    "tab.activeBackground": "#045980"//<--- BG: My Most Favourite.
}
```

Comment: now this applies to all Themes, limit the changes to a particular Theme

Comment: `applies to default theme` is incorrect, it applies to ALL Themes

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Hardik's answer, I went a little further to simplify it and make the top tabs stand out a little more, without the need for a named theme.

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": { 
        "tab.activeBorder": "#ff0000",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#045980", 
        "tab.inactiveBackground": "#505d63",
        "tab.inactiveForeground": "#f2f3f4"
    }
```

This just makes it so you can see which tabs are which in a dark theme.