# How to change the background color of the tab bar of vscode using settings.json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, themes

I've been following this tutorial by Coder Coder to make my vscode look better (tutorial link https://youtu.be/pGzssFNtWXw). As per the video I've opened the settings.json file and just wrote some code But when I can't be able to find the code to change the background of the tab-bar.([image: Tab-bar])

Here is what I've tried:

```
"tab.background" : "#000000"
```

Here is the code:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.background": "#000814",
        "sideBar.background": "#000d20",
        "sideBarTitle.foreground": "#ffd60a",
        "sideBarSectionHeader.foreground": "#ffd60a",
        "activityBar.activeBackground": "#ffea81d5",
        "activityBar.background": "#22223b",
        "statusBar.background": "#ffd60a",
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean editor tabs? If so, see one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843246/vscode-tab-color-not-responding-to-customization/67845465#67845465) on a similar post.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is the `editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a problem that I faced too but I found that to change the color of the tab-bar in settings.json you have to use the `editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground` command